# JOIN instead of subquery for related tags

Tags: sql, mysql, join, tagging, subquery

I have three tables, `bookmarks`, `tag` and `tagging`. `tagging` is the association table for linking tags to bookmarks. I would like to select related tags. The current query takes ages to run, but I could not wrap my head around the JOINs that could replace the subquery that selects all the related bookmarks that are tagged with specific tag IDs.

```
SELECT ta.name, count(*) 
FROM tagging t2 
JOIN tag ta ON t2.tag_id=ta.id  
WHERE t2.bookmark_id IN (
   SELECT bookmark_id 
   FROM tagging t1 
   WHERE t1.tag_id IN (1, 7) 
   GROUP BY t1.bookmark_id 
   HAVING COUNT(t1.id) = 2
) 
GROUP BY ta.id
```

Here is the result of the `EXPLAIN` of that query:

```
1   PRIMARY            ta  index PRIMARY    PRIMARY         8   NULL         3   
1   PRIMARY            t2  ref   tag_id_idx tag_id_idx      8   blinkz.ta.id 89   Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY t1  index tag_id_idx bookmark_id_idx 8   NULL         71   Using where
```

I have an index for the `bookmark_id` and `tag_id` fields in the `tagging` table. The `tag` table has a primary key named `id`

How could this query be optimised, preferably with a JOIN instead of a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poor performance is due to a [bug in MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32665) that will hopefully be fixed soon. Until then try this instead:

```
SELECT tag.name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tagging T1
JOIN tag
ON T1.tag_id = tag.id  
JOIN (
   SELECT bookmark_id 
   FROM tagging
   WHERE tag_id IN (1, 7) 
   GROUP BY bookmark_id 
   HAVING COUNT(id) = 2
) T2
ON T1.bookmark_id = T2.bookmark_id
GROUP BY tag.id
```

I'm assuming that there is a unique contraint on `(bookmark_id, tag_id)`.

Comment: That works fine! There is one small error, though: the HAVING should be COUNT(tagging.id) instead of COUNT(T1.id)

Comment: @chiborg: Thanks, fixed. By the way, if the id field is NOT NULL (which it probably is) then you could just write COUNT(*) instead.